# how to fix reload data

Tags: swift, reloaddata

I'm trying to take a text and find address that match and show them in a tableview - i found the addresses but the tableview dosent reload (i'm calling tableview.reloaddeta())

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Contacts


class LocationSearchTable : UITableViewController{


    var searchText:String?
    var matchingItems:[MKMapItem] = []
    var mapView: MKMapView? = nil
    var handleMapSelected:HandleMapSearch? = nil

    var locationDelegate : LocationDelegated?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return matchingItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark

        cell?.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name ?? "hiiha"

        return cell!
    }

}


extension LocationSearchTable : LocationDelegated{

    func setBar(_ searchText: String?) {

        guard let mapView = mapView, let searchBarText = searchText else {return}

        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { (response, err) in
            guard let response = response else{return}
            print(response.mapItems[0].name!)
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            print(self.matchingItems.count , " this is my size")
         *// i see that matchingItems is bigger then 0 but the tableview is allwaze empty*
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }



}
```

I expect the tableview to reload and show all the address

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `reloadData()` at the wrong place.

`search.start` works asynchronously. Move the line into the closure.

```
search.start { (response, err) in
    guard let response = response else { return }
    print(response.mapItems[0].name!)
    self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
    print(self.matchingItems.count , " this is my size")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And these lines are redundant

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

An `UITableViewController` has connected `dataSource` and `delegate` by default and one section is the default, too.

Comment: Then the error must be somewhere else. Are the `print` lines executed at all?

Comment: to solve the problem i put the tableview in the same view as the search bar, it did not solve the problem but went around it